# MS access report combining multiple databases

Tags: database, ms-access, reporting-services

I have 3 different ".mdb" databases (Microsoft Access)
let's say "Branch A","Branch B" and "Branch C" , they all have the same database design tables and everything and i want to generate one report combining them all
,something like this

```
Total Sales Report

Branch Name     Sales
Branch A        10000$
Branch B        23331$
Branch C        50000$
```

how can i do it , and is it possible with linked databases ?!
and can i use Cross-tab query combining them all too ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply link tables from the other .mdb databases and then run your report query which seems to be a union aggregate query from a *Sales Table* in each *Branch* database. Be sure to rename linked tables (*BranchASales*, *BranchBSales*, *BranchCSales*) if they share same name:

```sql
SELECT [Branch Name], Sum(Sales) As SumOfSales

FROM
   (SELECT 'Branch A' As [Branch Name], Sales FROM [BranchASales]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Branch B' As [Branch Name], Sales FROM [BranchBSales]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Branch C' As [Branch Name], Sales FROM [BranchCSales])

GROUP BY [Branch Name]
```

Alternatively, you can run queries calling sources outside the current database without any linked tables just as long as you specify the path. Likewise, you can query Excel workbooks, csv/txt files in this same approach:

```sql
SELECT [Branch Name], Sum(Sales) As SumOfSales    

FROM
   (SELECT 'Branch A' As [Branch Name], Sales FROM [C:\Path\To\Branch A.mdb].[Sales] 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Branch B' As [Branch Name], Sales FROM [C:\Path\To\Branch B.mdb].[Sales] 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Branch C' As [Branch Name], Sales FROM [C:\Path\To\Branch C.mdb].[Sales])

GROUP BY [Branch Name]
```

In above two queries, derived tables are used but the `FROM` clause `SELECT` query can easily be replaced with a separate, stored query (of same `SELECT`) in current database.